# What are valid use cases for -m2 in git revert for a merge commit?

Tags: git

Normally if I fubar a merge into a mainline branch and push it, the go-to command is:

```
$ git revert -m1 <merge commit SHA1>
```

However, I know that `revert` also can work with `-m2`. However, this does not make sense to me. I can't visualize what this does to the mainline branch, if the revert occurs on the first parent. Does this basically make the first parent now look like the second parent, minus any changes made in the merge commit itself? What does this actually do to the tree? Is there a valid set of use cases for this kind of revert which refers to the second parent?

Second parent will always be the feature / topic branch that was merged in, so I can't imagine you'd want to revert a mainline to that state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common use case is when someone botches a merge, usually on a `git pull`. When you do a pull that requires a merge, your *local* commits are the first parent, and the *remote* commits are the second. So let's say a developer hasn't pulled for a while, so his local branch is 20 commits behind `origin`. The developer makes a single commit, pulls, botches the merge somehow, and pushes. If we reverted that botched merge with `-m1`, we would lose the changes of all 20 of those commits and would have to cherry pick all of them. By using `-m2`, we just lose the changes from his single commit, and can then just cherry pick that if we wish.

Comment: I'm more amazed that a merge during pull works that way. I would have expected the merge to appear the same way that a feature branch merge would look since they are technically the same thing.

Comment: When you merge in a feature branch, you do so while you are on the main branch, and it is the main branch that moves; that is what makes it the primary parent. When you do a git pull, you are on your local branch, and it is your local branch that moves, so it is the primary parent.